# Препроцессорные функции С++ (#define)

Tags: visual-c++, c++

Здравствуйте.

По сути вопрос не большой. Прочитал, что если объявить `#define A`, то этот макрос будет расцениваться как макрос который может принять значение 0 или 1, поэтому его пишут без указания значения. Далее макрос `#ifdef A` означает условие истинно(`А объявлено`), а если `#ifndef A`, то A объявлено не было.

В примере вот так:

```
 #define BUG

 #ifdef BUG

 void function() {...}

 #endif
```

Пишу так же в Visual Studio Express 2010 и выходит ошибка:
`fatal error C1017: invalid integer constant expression`

Если же сделать так:

```
 #define BUG 1

 #ifdef BUG //или #if(BUG)

 void function() {...}

 #endif
```

То все работает прекрасно.

Вопрос: Почему нельзя задать макрос без указания значения, хотя в примере это есть и воде как работает?

Comment: Сложный вопрос. g++ так не капризничает. Т.е. на `#ifdef BUG` реагирует нормально, а бред `#if(BUG)` отвергает, поскольку после подстановки пустого BUG получаем `#if()`, что не есть нормальные оператор препроцессора.

И ещё. Препроцессор же есть отдельный от транслятора, называется cpp

Comment: А в обычном C так можно?

Comment: Как так? Там разные варианты.

Comment: Ну я имел ввиду в обычном C, объявить `#define NAME`и он не ругался что значение не присвоено.

Comment: Так вот именно по описанной вами выше причине, нельзя после `#define BUG`  писать `#if(BUG)`, только `#ifdef BUG`, только хардкор. Однако вся проблема в том, что С++ даже так не воспринимает.

Comment: Это же vc++. 

Что вы все ждете от людей, которые решили продолжать использовать `\` для разделителя файлов и cp-1251 вместо уже существовавшей iso-8859-5?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Между `#ifdef` и `#if` есть некоторая разница, о которой можно почитать, например, [здесь](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/If.html). В двух словах - `#if` ожидает некоторое выражение, для которого можно вычислить степень истины, а `#ifdef` ожидает имя макроса и выдаёт результат его определённости (если макрос был определён, 1, иначе 0).

Comment: Да дело даже не в этом, просто `#define NAME` не работает пока не дашь ему конкретное значение, не важно, что дальше `#if` или `#ifdef`...

Comment: Да, теперь вижу - правда, всё дело в том, что это, вероятно, специфично для Visual Studio (на http://support.microsoft.com/kb/69934 об этом рассказывают более подробно). Кстати, в gcc твой код компилируется абсолютно без проблем.

Comment: Спасибо) А какие преимущества у g++ перед стандартным компилятором Visual Studio?)

Comment: Сложно сказать, потому что у каждого компилятора свои преимущества :) Я использую linux в качестве основной платформы для программирования, поэтому мне ближе gcc (как минимум, потому что он есть в базовой поставке)

Comment: @BlackOverlord учитывая свободное, без излишнего трепета отношение MS к стандартам, я бы поостерёгся называть компилятор MS VC "стандартными". Традиционно g++ ближе к стандартному...

Answer (score 2):

Бред какой-то. Сам делал так сто раз в разных версиях студии (в том числе и 2010 Express) и работало. Да и в стандартной библиотеке широко используются `#define` для защиты от повторного включения заголовочных файлов.

ОБНОВЛЕНИЕ:
 Код из вопроса правильный и не выдаёт ошибок:
    #define BUG
    #ifdef BUG
    void function() {...}
    #endif

А такой код неправильный

```
#define BUG
#if BUG
void function() {...}
#endif
```

И компилятор выдаёт ту самую ошибку, про которую BlackOverlord писал. Видимо, он опечатался в браузере и написал без ошибки. Если так, то ответ на вопрос уже есть по ссылке из предыдущего ответа.

Comment: Почему бред? У человека конкретная проблема и я не вижу оснований не верить ему в том, что проблема имеет место быть и вполне воспроизводима.